# Reclaim space from dropped column when there isn't enough space for index rebuild

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I dropped a char(10) column from a table that has about 111 million rows (30gb data, 11gb index)

I then ran an index rebuild on the clustered index.  This ate up all the space on the drive containing the database.

I then ran `dbcc cleantable` and got all the space back, plus a few more gigs.

Is there a way to reclaim space from the dropped column when there isn't enough space for index rebuild?

Or did the `cleantable` operation actually reclaim the space?  (I know it reclaimed space, but I'm guessing it's possible it reclaimed space for a different reason, since cleantable isn't suggested as the way to reclaim space after dropping a column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBCC CLEANTABLE` can only be used to [reclaim space left from dropping a *variable* length column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174418.aspx).  Thus it cannot be considered a "good" replacement for rebuilding the table/index.

Since you state that the column you dropped was a *fixed* length column, I can only surmise there must be some other reason for unused, but allocated space being present in the table; perhaps ghost records or perhaps you actually dropped some other columns as well that actually were variable length.